# Can't figure out how to center a div to the page

Tags: html, styling

I have two blocks of text with colored background. I want them to sit next to each other and then be horizontally centered on the page but I can't get them to center on the page. Also I have to use inline styling because I am just coding on wordpress for work. Help!

```
<div align="center">
<div style="background-color: #526f87; width: 60%; float: left; height: 160px; " >
<p style="font-size: 40px; color: #b9cbea; letter-spacing: 2px; line-height: 110%; padding-top: 20px; padding-right: 20px; text-align: right;">YOU'RE NEEDED AT THE TOP </p>
<p style="font-size: 40px; color: white; letter-spacing: 2px; line-height: 110%; padding-bottom: 20px; padding-right: 20px; text-align: right;" ><strong>MEET US THERE</strong>
</p>
</div>
<div style="background-color: #526f87; width: 20%; float: left; margin-left: 10px; height: 160px;">
<p style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px;" align="center">22 ICF CEUs <br /><span style="font-size: 12px;">(12.17 Core Competencies / 10.25 Resource Development)</span></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should know that there is a trick for centering divs on the page. If you want to center some content, you know what its `width` will be, right? So you can use:

```
width: /* something */;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

So for your code snippet, I recommend using `flex` if you're not targetting old browsers. I would do something like this:

```html
<div style="display: flex; width: 80%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
  <div style="flex: 3">this is the larger div to the left</div>
  <div style="flex: 1">this is the one that should fall on the right</div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** My code keeps proportions with the ones in your code.

Comment: Your wrapper div has align="center" which will not apply to floated children. First, stick to the style attribute (or use a stylesheet). Second, define the width and use Victor's answer on the wrapper like so.... style="width: 500px; position:relative;". If you don't define position, then your floated children will be 60%, 20% of another element. Victor's answer will then work to center the wrapper horizontally. Vertical positioning is another topic.

Comment: Great thanks! I used the flex code and it worked perfectly!

Comment: @ZoieYoung, but keep in mind that the [compatibility table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is pretty... restrictive.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please upvote and accept it! Thanks!